# Update the route to just show resource/new as compared to user/user_id/resource/new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, routes

I am using rails 4 along with devise my `routes.rb`  reads :

```
devise_for :users, :path => '',
  :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :sign_up => 'register'},
  controllers: { registrations: "registrations", omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks' } do
    get "/login" => "devise/sessions#new"
    get "/signup" => "devise/registrations#new"
    get "/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
    get "/login" => "devise/sessions#new"
end


resources :users, :only => [:show, :index], :path => "bloggers" do
    resources :posts, :path => "articles"
end
```

Now when I create a new post as the currently signed in user (lets say the id is 1). The URL on the `Post -> New` action reads - > `https://localhost:3000/bloggers/1/articles/new` but I want to show 
`https://localhost:3000/articles/new`, as the new action on the post should always be associated to the current_user.

I would imagine this being possible, but no clue how to do it.

Also a `user has_many posts`.

Help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Authentication**

Very simple actually:

```
#config/routes.rb
# If you have overridden "path_names", you don't need other paths for Devise
devise_for :users, :path => '',
   :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :sign_up => 'register'},
   controllers: { registrations: "registrations", omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks' }

resources :posts, as: "articles", path: "articles"

#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_action :authenticate_user!, except: :index

   def index
      #Stuff here
   end

end
```

The bottom line here is that whenever you want to use an authenticated area (especially with Devise), you just need to "protect" the `controller#actions` which you want to limit access to. The beauty is that you can use the [`authenticate_user!`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers) helper method to make these work

Further to that, you will then be able to just call `current_user` in your controller (not having to set the user, as you're doing now):

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def new
       @post = current_user.posts.new
   end

   def create
       @post = current_user.posts.new post_params
       @post.save
   end

   private

   def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:x, :y, :z)
   end
end
```